# How to query data for one week per time in mySQL

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am using python 3.4 to query the data in mysql. I would like to query one year's worth of data from a large database so I plan to split the query to query for one week per time.

This is the query I am using to query the data.

```
SELECT id, event_title, event_deadline FROM job
WHERE country_id = 15
AND (event_deadline >= '2015-01-01' AND event_deadline <= '2015-01-07')
```

Is there an easier way to grab all the data for all 52 weeks in a year without manually listing out the dates for each week like below?

```
week 1: 2015-01-01 - 2015-01-07
week 2: 2015-01-08 - 2015-01-14
week 3: 2015-01-15 - 2015-01-21
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the MySQL `WEEK()` function, something like this: (Forgive me if this looks like php; I haven't done much python. Nonetheless, the principle is the same.)

```
query = ("SELECT id, event_title, event_deadline FROM job "
            "WHERE country_id = 15 "
              "AND WEEK(event_deadline) = %s")

for weeknum in [1..53]
    cursor.execute(query, weeknum)
    do_stuff_with(cursor)
```

Check the MySQL docs for details on how [Mysql's WEEK() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) defines a calendar week.

Hope that makes enough sense to be useful.